# How to search exact word match and get exact result in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

how to search exact number

this code is working like this

if i search 12345678(this is complete no) it is showing nothing

after that if i search this no 1234567(this is not complete no)

so it is showing result like this

like this

```
12345678
12345678
12348591
12346899
12345698
```

and i want a result like that

if i search this no 12345678 (this is complete no)

so it is showing exact like this

```
12345678
12345678
```

how can i do this please help me to fix this issue

and this is code

```
<?php

    //connect to database

     mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
     mysql_select_db('member');

$alphabet = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'); 
foreach ($alphabet as $letter) { 
echo "<a href=\"viewuser.php?letter=" . $letter . "\" class=\"style2\">" . $letter . "</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;"; 

} 


echo "<br>";
echo "<a href=\"index.php?\" class=\"style2\">Show All</a></p><br /> <form method=\"post\" action=\"?\">

        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"letter\" value=\"{$_GET['letter']}\" />";


$page = (empty($_GET['page'])) ? 1 : $_GET['page'];
$letter = (empty($_GET['letter'])) ? "%" : $_GET['letter'];
$name = (empty($_GET['name'])) ? "%male" : $_GET['name'];
?></td>
            </tr>

            <p> 
              <?php

//get date
$button = $_GET['submit'];
$search = $_GET['search'];

$s = $_GET['s'];
if (!$s)

$s = 0;
$e = 12;

$next = $s + $e; $prev = $s - $e;
    if (strlen($search)<=1)
   echo "";

    else
   {
     echo "<class=\"style2\"> You searched for <b>$search</b>";

     //connect to database

     mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
     mysql_select_db('member');



 //explode search term
           $search_exploded = explode(" ",$search);
           foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
    $str = mysql_real_escape_string(substr($search_each, 0, 9));
    //construct query
    $x++;
    if ($x==1) $construct .= "number LIKE '$str%'";

}




        //echo out construct

  $construct = "SELECT * FROM workorder WHERE $construct";

    $run = mysql_query($construct);
     $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);
       if ($foundnum==0)
        echo "<class=\"style2\">No user found.";
     else
     {






 ?>






<?php

 echo "<class=\"style2\"><p>$foundnum results found.</p>";

       while ($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
              {
echo "<table class='hovertable' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
echo "<tr><th>User name</th><th>Number</th><th>Exchange</th><th>Cabnint</th><th>Service</th><th>Open Date</th><th>Close Date</th><th>Remaks</th><th>Status</th><th>Edit</th><th>Detail</th><th>Delete</th></tr>";

if ($runrows > 0) {
        while($runrows = mysql_fetch_array($run)) {
                echo "<tr><td>";
             echo $runrows['username'];
            echo "</td><td>";
                echo $runrows['number'];
                echo "</td><td>";
            echo $runrows['exchange'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $runrows['cabnint'];
                echo "</td><td>";
        echo $runrows['service'];
                echo "</td><td>";
        echo $runrows['opendate'];
                echo "</td><td>";
        echo $runrows['closedate'];
                echo "</td><td>";
        echo $runrows['remaks'];
                echo "</td><td>";
        echo $runrows['status'];
                echo "</td><td>";
            echo '<a href="edit.php?id=' . $runrows['id'] . '" class="style2">Edit</a>';
        echo "</td><td>";
            echo '<a href="detail.php?id=' . $runrows['id'] . '" class="style2">Detail</a>';
        echo "</td><td>";
            echo '<a href="delete.php?id=' . $runrows['id'] . '" class="style2">Delete</a>';
                echo "</td></tr>";

        }
} else {
        echo "<tr><td colspan=\"5\">No results found!</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
       }

     }



    }
?>
```

Comment: don't put the same question twice, I have answered on your previous question, please check that

Comment: but ur answer is incorrect thats why i ask here again

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, my answer would not be match your requirement, but you don't ask the same question again I am not blaming you for asking same question again, you are new user as per SO rule if your keep on asking the question like this they will block your account, so for your welfare and to keep the forum quality only I am saying this. Hope you can understand me.

Comment: its oky no problem dear

Answer (score 1):

To search for exact number you need to remove `LIKE`, change:

```
if ($x==1) $construct .= "number LIKE '$str%'";
```

to

```
if ($x==1) $construct .= "number = $str";
```

you are looping the results 2 times, by doing:

```
while ($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
..
if ($runrows > 0) {
        while($runrows = mysql_fetch_array($run)) {
```

just change it to:

```
if ($runrows > 0) {
        while($runrows = mysql_fetch_array($run)) {
```

Comment: i replace your code but its showing nothing result

Comment: it is showing 1 results found msg but no result showing

Comment: @user2903400 check your previous question on that I have answered check that and reply me

Comment: sudhiar i replace ur code again but its not working